# How to run Angular2 Project on Cloud Foundry consisting of gulp,bower?

Tags: angular, gulp, cloud-foundry

I am trying to upload this [angular2-advance-seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) project and to upload on cloud foundry instance I just added .cfignore and manifest file to the project.

.cfignore file

```
node_modules
nativescript
.docker
.git
.github
.vscode
dist
```

manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: project-name
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  #command:  DEBUG=express:* node app.js
  command:  npm run start
#services:

env:
    node_env: cloud
```

I installed `gulp-cli` to run all the gulp commands but it is still not working and shows this error:

```
 OUT > gulp serve.dev --color
 ERR     [09:59:02] Failed to load external module ts-node/register
 ERR [09:59:02] Failed to load external module typescript-require
 ERR [09:59:02] Try running: npm install gulp
 ERR npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
 ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "start"
 ERR npm ERR! node v4.5.0
 ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no cloud-foundry buildpack for executing gulp commands after all node dependencies have been installed.

There is a script in `package.json` called `build.prod`, which will create a production distribution version of the project in `dist/prod`folder.
you can run it with `npm run build.prod` command.

Now, to push project on cloud foundry instance, first you need to login into  the cloud foundry with `cf login`. and create a `manifest.yml` file in the main project directory as following.

```
#manifest.yml

---
applications:
- name: PROJECT_NAME
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  path: dist/prod
```

or after login in cloud foundry instance,you could simply run this command in `dist/prod`folder.

```
cf push PROJECT_NAME -m 64M -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
```

Comment: HTTP server doesn't fallback to index.html as stated here : https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml